# set default value for select menu from mongodb

Tags: reactjs, joi

I have a dropdown list which is populated from a database. The first option is 'none' (actual record in database with objectId) which should be the default option and only needs to be changed if the user wants to, otherwise it should just use that initial value when submitting the form. However, even though it is selected and has a valid objectId, I still get a validation error saying the field is empty. The validation error only goes away if I select something else from the select menu or select something else and then select 'none' again. I am using [Joi-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-browser) for validation.

```
schema = {
    subcategoryId: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Subcategory"),
}
```

This is the select menu:

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group controlId="subcategoryId">
          <Form.Label>Sub-category</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            as="select"
            name="subcategoryId"
            value={this.state.data.subcategoryId}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            error={this.state.errors.subcategory}
          >
            {this.state.subcategories.map(subcategory => (
              <option key={subcategory._id} value={subcategory._id}>
                {subcategory.name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Form.Control>
          {this.state.errors.subcategoryId && (
            <Alert variant="danger">
              {this.state.errors.subcategoryId}
            </Alert>
          )}
        </Form.Group>
```

And here is my state:

```
  state = {
    data: {
      name: "",
      description: "",
      categoryId: "",
      subcategoryId: "",
      price: ""
    },
    categories: [],
    subcategories: [],
    errors: {}
  };

const { data: subcategories } = await getSubcategories();
this.setState({ subcategories });
```

And this is the html output of the dropdown's first field which I want selected by default:

```
<option value="5d4b42d47b454712f4db7c67">None</option>
```

The error I get back is that the category Id cannot be empty, yet each option in the select menu has a value. I am new to react but perhaps the value is only actually assigned upon change?

Comment: Could you add what form library you're using?

Comment: Are you referring to the validation? Joi.

Comment: Yes, is it a client or server side validation error? Can you post your Joi validation object you're using for this form?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Client side.

Comment: What code uses your `schema`? Where do you specify it?

Comment: `validate = () => {
    const options = { abortEarly: false };
    const result = Joi.validate(this.state.data, this.schema, options);
    if (!result.error) return null;

    const errors = {};
    for (let item of result.error.details) errors[item.path[0]] = item.message;
    return errors;
  };` This is called upon form submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit `componentDidMount`. After you get your subcategories, you'll need to set the state to of `this.state.data.subcategoryId` to one of the categories. This is because you're using a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). Otherwise, it'll still be set to `""`, which isn't one of the valid values for the `<select>` component, and likely why it's failing validation.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  // getting a copy of this.state.data so as not to mutate state directly
  const data = { ...this.state.data };
  const { data: subcategories } = await getSubcategories();

  // filter the array to a new array of subcategories that have the name === 'none'
  const arrayOfSubcategoriesWhereNameIsNone = subcategories.filter(i => i.name === 'none');

  const getIdOfFirstElementOfArray = arrayOfSubcategoriesWhereNameIsNone [0]._id;

  //set getIdOfFirstElementOfArray equal to the function's local copy of this.state.data.subcategoryId
  data.subcategoryId = getIdOfFirstElementOfArray;

  // update the state with the mutated object (the function's local copy of this.state.data)
  this.setState({ subcategories, data });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to keep my code the same and incorporate yours but I still get the validate error. `const { data: subcategories } = await getSubcategories();

    subcategories.subcategoryId = subcategories.filter(
      i => i.name === "None"
    )[0]._id;

    this.setState({ subcategories });` Then in the select menu for value I put:  `value={
                      this.state.data.subcategoryId ||
                      this.state.subcategories.subcategoryId
                    }`

Comment: is the `none` option coming back from your database?

Comment: Yes. I have react extension installed in google dev tools and the correct object id is there as a value. And all the options are available in the dropdown too.

Comment: Actually, your code works 100% when I tested it. If possible could you please edit your answer with some comments about what is happening? I can see you are starting with the spread operator then it looks like destructuring so subcategories can be accessed without having to use data.subcategories. Then getting the object for the 'none' value and setting the state. But I don't really understand the 'data' part when you set the state. And I am probably wrong about the beginning too :-P